# Hibernate & spring MVC with websphere 6.1 & RAD 7

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, websphere, ibm-rad

I need to know currently what versions of spring mvc & hibernate will work with IBM websphere application server 6.1 [using RAD 7  / J2ee 1.4 & java 1.5] and back-end db2 via websphere connection pool , Any example with be more useful  . I need to create a small application with configuration date to pick from db2 database via websphere 6.1 application server connection pool using hibernate and display using spring mvc in front-end

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 3 works, i've used it on WAS 6.1 to access DB2 & Oracle databases with no problems.
Spring MVC i didn't use. But other Spring components work without a hitch